# How to change Chrome App Caption Bar color in Windows 10

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

[image: Google Earth as in Chrome App Window]

You can see how the caption/title bar has the same color as the navigation menu on the left.

Though as far as I know this only works on Android/IOS/Windows Phone, but this is first time I see it in Chrome.

Version is: `69.0.3497.81 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: 69_win_81)`

How do I accomplish this? I tried several options I've found on Stackoverflow, but none of them worked. Such as:

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#999999" />
<meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#4285f4">
```

The first only appears to work on Chrome browsers that are running on Android. The second option I'm not sure for what that is.

So! How do I do it??
[image: myApp.html Chrome App Window]

Chrome parameters for launching .html documents as Chrome App Window:

```
"...\chrome.exe" -app="file:\\\\...\myApp.html"
```

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about setting your [Web App Manifest](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/)

Comment: Exactly what I needed. But is there a way to use that manifest via .html?
Because I can't create a shortcut via Create Shortcut on Desktop option that Chrome provides. Therefore using the manifest wouldn't work in this case.

Any possibilities with standard .html? Because me uploading and changing the same exact document via file manager is not so easy.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. The manifest.json get's declared in your html as an external file, or inline like `<link rel="manifest" href='data:application/manifest+json,{ "name": "My Cool Web App", "short_name": "CoolWeb", "description": "It is beer oclock!"}' ................etc........./>`

Comment: The thing is, that only "works" via the website URL. But I want this to work with the standalone .HTML document. Not the standard website URL like http://facebook.com for example. My "application" is loading from file:///C:/users.../Desktop/myApp.html. Is there a way to assign the manifest to it? So the Chrome thinks it's an "Web Store Application" or "Extension".

Basically. Taking a .HTML document, and treating it as an installed extension via manifest.json file, therefore being able to assign the caption bar color with "background_color": "#000",

Comment: See the inline example? That would sit in the standalone html file, wherein `href='data:application/manifest+json,{ "name"..............` has the object where you would include your colors and everything as specified in that first link as possible attributes instead of in an external json file because it's inline and all sits nicely in the one single html file :)

Comment: Or as example `<link rel="manifest" href='data:application/manifest+json,{ "display":"standalone","theme_color":"#FF0000"}'/>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple do this in head tags. It would work as tested already

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#1c307d">
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. I know how to do it because the question was made 2 years ago, but your answer will be accepted because it is correct 

Comment: Thanks! @SoricyInfinitive Hopefully it would be benefitial for upcoming people on this page/question.