# (Translation) I want to keep overrides without dev tools

Tags: java, jquery, google-chrome

I want to change the title bar color of the Google Create shortcut window.
The left is the basic state, and the right is the appearance of adding functions through elements.

[image: Image bar diagramm]

From [How to change Chrome App Caption Bar color in Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52228097/how-to-change-chrome-app-caption-bar-color-in-windows-10)
I changed the title color by referring to the link above. Answer at the bottom.

I want to keep this state from when I turn it on, but it doesn't work without dev tools.
I wanted to keep this state, so I looked for a way, but [this was the only hopeful comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51522923/local-overrides-in-chrome-keep-active-while-devtools-are-closed).

How can I use 'Custom JavaScript for Websites 2' to keep title bar color without dev tools?

[image: dev tool]

Comment: Have you tried plugins?

Comment: thank you very much for the comment.
Is a plugin an extension?
After installing that extension
'<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><meta name="theme-color" content="#131722"></head>'.
I entered the above text and tried to save it, but nothing happened. I tried changing the settings, but it was the same.

Comment: Yes, something like [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha). But you'll have to play around with CSS. If you can share the HTML you want to change maybe we can help you better.

Comment: I tried to edit the post and attach it, but the !DOCTYPE htm part is not output.
I downloaded the html file of the Trading View site (this is a shortcut site I want to change).
And I also downloaded the file that I modified and applied.
How do I attach a file? May I send it to you by e-mail?
I'm really sorry I don't know anything.

Comment: Can you past here the changes you made either in HTML or CSS? You probably just need to add CSS to the extension to change the `body` background color.

Comment: <meta name="theme-color" content="#131722">  
This is it.
It does not work when used on the body part, but works when used on the head part. To check this, you need to confirm with Create Shortcut or on the Google App window.

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-manipulator/mdhellggnoabbnnchkeniomkpghbekko/related

Comment: I found this extension.
I put the same sentence in the html file and applied it, but there was no change. Is it difficult to change the head with an extension?a

Answer (score 0):

You should use an extension like [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha) or [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-manipulator/mdhellggnoabbnnchkeniomkpghbekko/related) and inject CSS like:

```
body {
  background-color: #131722;
}
```

If you want to change the top bar in the image you posted, that's Google Chrome. Try [Dark Mode](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/9275525?co=GENIE.Platform=Android&hl=en).

Comment: No change. The title bar color does not change. Whatever is written to the body part. The head should change. Maybe I don't understand... It's too difficult.

Comment: That's because the title bar is another element. What is the website url? Can you post a print screen of the changes you made in DevTools?

Comment: Can you please see the text? Added. I put the text I wanted right under the line that was clicked with a blue background.

Comment: Wait. It seems you want to change the color of the top bar in Google Chrome, not the website, is that correct? Have you tried [Dark Mode in Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/9275525?co=GENIE.Platform=Android&hl=en)?

Comment: Sadly I'm using dark mode. It does not apply to shortcut windows. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/material-dark/npadhaijchjemiifipabpmeebeelbmpd

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resolved.
You can use this extension.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/permanent-inspect-element/alfgclaljdbleenfjjnkefddlgbknl
After editing the element, you can save it.
But the downside is that the site is too slow. The evaluation is also complex. I think it will be a good tool for some. For me, this tool is too inconvenient. I'm looking for a better way.

Comment: <https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sourceditor/eonnlpadjpdnandpobhloihongackbpg> There are extensions that take out elements.
After making changes, you can save them.
The site I'm using has an error and I can't use it. I'm so sad. However, the extension itself has good ratings and seems to be good because many people use it.